# Rect's equivalent to text's text-anchor presentation attribute?

Tags: svg, d3.js

Is there a rect's equivalent to text's text-anchor presentation attribute?

I want to be able to position a rect from its left/right side or depending on the situation. I know that it could be done with some simple calculations, but I'm just wondering if something already built-in exists.

Link on text-anchor presentation attribute...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

Answer (score 8):

I was searching for the same question, and found this post with no answer. The question is pretty old, but i put here the solution for someone may look for it as i did.

When one specifies (x, y) of a svg rect it is treated like: *"Place the left top corner of the rect at the point (x, y)"*. But one may want (x, y) to be treated as: *"Hey, place the center of my rect at (x, y)"* or *"Hey, place the top right corner of my rect at (x, y)"*. For this anchor mechanics is used, but there is no such in svg.

**You can still achieve anchor mechanics** with transform (using css or attribute). It is possible since percent values in transform.translate are calculated relative to applied shape, but not its parent.

**THE SOLUTION WORKS ONLY IN CHROME FOR NOW**

So to achieve *"Hey, place the center of my rect at (x, y)"* you need to set anchor to (0.5, 0.5). Here how it is done with transform:

```
.rect-anchor-50-50 {
  /* 
    Precents in translate are calculated relative to
    the applied rectangle, but not its parent.
    Set anchor to (0.5, 0.5) or (center, center).
    */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

---

## Code Snippet on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5vk0dk/1/)

```css
.rect-anchor-0-0 {
  fill: #afafaf;
}
.rect-anchor-50-50 {
  /* 
    precents in translate are calculated relative to
    the applied rectangle, but not its parent
    */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  fill: #afcfae;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.group {
  fill: red;
}
svg {
  fill: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!-- One can use translate with percents to achieve anchor like mechanics -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">
  <rect fill="lightblue" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>

  <!-- Use translate to achieve anchor mechanics -->
  <rect class="rect-anchor-0-0" x="150" y="150" width="200" height="35" />
  <rect class="rect-anchor-50-50" x="150" y="150" width="200" height="35" />

  <!-- Rect x,y position mark for convenience -->
  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="2" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Note from 2019: The JSFiddle example appears the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it right after appending:

```
    .append('rect')
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 5)
      // Center rectangle
      .attr('transform', function() {
        return `translate(-${this.getAttribute('width') / 2}` +
          `, -${this.getAttribute('height') / 2})`;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this for other SVG elements (including `rect`), see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html). You'll have to calculate the position yourself.